# Groups in derived series are normal in the whole group

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, geometric-group-theory

I am considering a finitely generated, solvable group $G$ which has subexponential growth. Let $G=G_0\vartriangleright G_1\vartriangleright....\vartriangleright G_d\vartriangleright G_{d+1}=1$ denote the derived series of G.

It should be the case that $G_d$ is normal in $G$. Does anyone know why this is true?
I don't know whether all of the assumptions above are necessary for the result.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't all of the groups be normal in G, except maybe $ G_0 $ if it is non Abelian? Since each group is a subgroup of the one before it, and the first one is normal by that notation, they should all be normal. Or what do you mean otherwise by those triangles?

Comment: They are all normal in their respective predecessor.

Comment: So what you are essentially asking is, does the group normal satisfy the transitive law?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact all the subgroups $G_i$ are normal in $G$ for let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ then $N'$ is normal in $G$. To see this let $[n_1,n_2]$ be a commutator in $N'$ then $[n_1,n_2]^g = [n_1^g, n_2^g] = [n'_1,n'_2] \in N'$  $ \forall g \in G$.

Comment: I see, that was easy. Thank you. You didn't say what $N'$ was though, I did the proof by induction over $i$ instead.

Comment: $N'$ is the standard notation for the derived subgroup of $N$ (the commutator subgroup).